# How to assign a Series to a DataFrame from a Panel?

Tags: pandas

I have a Panel

```
quotes_cc_returns
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 132 (major_axis) x 7 (minor_axis)
Items axis: VFINX to VWESX
Major_axis axis: 2001-01-31 00:00:00 to 2011-12-31 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to CC_Returns
```

and I can add a column which has a subtraction

```
quotes_premiums = quotes_cc_returns.transpose(2, 1, 0)

quotes_premiums['RiskPremium'] = quotes_premiums.CC_Returns.sub(ff_data_factors_subset.RF, axis=0)
```

but I'm unable to add a column with a simple assignment

```
quotes_premiums['MktRiskPremium'] = ff_data_factors_subset.MktMinusRF
```

because it returns this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 411, in <module>
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 243, in calcRiskPremiums
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\panel.py", line 668, in __setitem__
    raise AssertionError()
AssertionError:
```

ff_data_factors_subset.MktMinusRF is a Series with the same length and index as quotes_premiums['MktRiskPremium'].

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using this code:

```
quotes_premiums['MktRiskPremium'] = 0.0
quotes_premiums['MktRiskPremium'] = quotes_premiums.MktRiskPremium.add(ff_data_factors_subset.MktMinusRF, axis=0)
```

JM

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use `.loc` to select the items and major axes where the new series should go. Here's an example that might help you sort it out.

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(6), 'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one']})

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   A    B
0  0  one
1  1  one
2  2  two
3  3  two
4  4  one
5  5  one

[6 rows x 2 columns]

In [18]: wp = pd.Panel({'L1': df, 'L2': df})

In [19]: other = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 7))
```

So to it in just item 'L1':

```
In [20]: wp.loc['L1', :, 'other'] = other

In [22]: wp['L1']
Out[22]: 
   A    B other
0  0  one     1
1  1  one     2
2  2  two     3
3  3  two     4
4  4  one     5
5  5  one     6

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Hello. Using your example I get a KeyError: 'other' message. I'm using Python 2.7.3 and Pandas 0.12.0. However, what I really want is to add a column to all panel items. That column values should be a Series, which has the same length and index of the panel. In my example by transposing the panel and adding the column using a subtraction works. What doesn't work is adding the column by using an assignment. Thanks.